# Rates of charging in an RC circuit when components are partly charged initially

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

Just to be sure of my reasoning I am describing a simplified version of my problem
Two capacitors of capacitance $C_1$ and $C_2$ are connected in series to a battery of emf  $V$ volts having some internal resistance.Capacitor $C_1$ is charged prior to being placed in the circuit with charge $q$ on either plates which is less than the final charge it would have held if placed in the circuit in uncharged state.How do I find time dependent rates for the charging of both capacitors separately ? 
I know how to do that for a single capacitor and resistor in series with battery but here I have two capacitors and one is having some charge on it initially.
Initially I thought I will consider the charge present on $C_1$ and find potential difference across it and subtract it from battery emf to get a starting potential difference which charges both capacitors but I'm not sure whether this is valid or not , moreover $C_1$ will finally reach the amount of charge it can hold if it had been connected uncharged,  what after that given that th other capacitor hasn't reached it's full charged state , how does it get charged then , because it's in series it has to pull charges from one plate of other capacitor if it has to charge but doing so will lead $C_1$ to overshoot it's maximum charge threshold  (for the series circuit) . Someone explaining the step by step mechanism of this is highly needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Initially I thought I will consider the charge present on C1 and find
>   potential difference across it and subtract it from battery emf to get
>   a starting potential difference which charges both capacitors but I'm
>   not sure whether this is valid or not

Yes, it's valid since you're simply changing the initial conditions.  Proceeding as usual for the series RC circuit, simply add a term for the voltage across the second capacitor as so:

(1) KVL ($r$ is the internal resistance of the battery)

$$V = v_r(t) + v_{C1}(t) + v_{C2}(t)$$

(2) Differentiate with respect to time

$$0 = \dot v_r(t) + \dot v_{C1}(t) + \dot v_{C2}(t) = \frac{di}{dt}r + \frac{i}{C_1} + \frac{i}{C_2}$$

(3) Solve the differential equation

$$i(t) = i(0)\,e^{-t/rC_{eq}}$$

where

$$\frac{1}{C_{eq}} = \frac{1}{C_1}+\frac{1}{C_2}$$

and

$$i(0) = \frac{v_r(0)}{r}=\frac{V - v_{C_1}(0) - v_{C_2}(0)}{r}$$

Now that you have found the series current $i(t)$, you can find the voltage across each capacitor as so

$$v_{C1}(t) = v_{C1}(0) + \frac{1}{C_1}\int_0^ti(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau$$

and similarly for $v_{C2}(t)$.

Calculate these voltages yourself and verify that their sum approaches $V$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$.